# How do I reflect custom attributes on a reference property without getting ones attached to the class?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, custom-attributes

Lets say I have:

```
[Description("Class Description")]
public class A { }

public class B { 
    public A PropertyA { get;set;}
}
```

When I reflect on PropertyA, I see the attributes of class A.  Why?

```
var entityProperties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(B)).Cast<PropertyDescriptor>();
foreach (var a in entityProperties.First().Attributes)
    Console.Out.Write(a.GetType().ToString());
```

prints out:

```
System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute
```

Why is the DescriptionAttribute in the list when i reflect on the property?  How do I exclude class attributes and just get ones attached to the property?

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
foreach (var a in entityProperties.First().Attributes)
```

to:

```
foreach (var a in entityProperties.First().GetCustomAttributes(true))
```

The documentation for the `GetCustomAttributes()` method is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dzdb2077(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: PropertyDescriptor doesn't seem to have a GetCustomAttributes().  However, PropertyInfo does.  If I switch the code around to get PropertyInfos instead, it seems to work better.. but why?